# Is memtest relialable?

Tags: bsod, memtest86+

when i start to play some demanding game my computer either restart with BSOD without any usefull information right away or system starts to act weird (weird chars in browser, unstability). System is otherwise stable when i only browsr or so.

So i gues it can be only RAM problem (i tried to switch to different memmory slot and CPU was recently changed.)

I let it to run memtest (bundled with lastest opensuse) for 45min to 1 pass and it showed no error, i never really used memtest so im not sure if i use it correctly.
[image: memtest screenshot]

EDIT: CPU-Z Image
[image: Cpuz memmory and spd]

Comment: When you get the BSOD what is the error message detail? This will greatly assist in identifying the problem. Also, you mention your CPU was recently changed: was it upgraded or replaced through a fault? This could be a possible reason you keep getting BSODs as it may be a faulty motherboard...

Comment: If RAM errors are caused by `memory cells crosstalk effects`, then ramtests are only partially reliable. They mostly don't know the physical structure of the RAM modules to test this effects.

Comment: BSOD is different everytime, and doesnt seem to be much data in it. I will take a shot when it happens again. CPU was changed to higher model, error rate seems to be the same, or maybe little higher. I dont think its motherboard cause it only happens when some game is using a lot of memmory.

Comment: *it only happens when some game is using a lot of memory*... You're making the implicit assumption that certain parts of your physical memory modules aren't used until "a lot" of RAM is in use. That's incorrect. Windows uses a technique known as [Address space layout randomization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) that results in some code at least being loaded in random physical locations in memory.

Comment: post some pictures of CPU-Z (Memory and SPD tab).

Comment: OK, i added CPU-Z image

Comment: @forstjiri Are you saying that this problem was also happening *before* the CPU change?

Comment: @Andrew Morton Yes it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BSOD issues happen because the RAM timings are wrong. Your RAM runs at 767MHz and uses the timings for 666MHz instead of the ones which it should use. It should use the 800 timings which are 10-10-10-27-36.

So, go into the BIOS and change the RAM timings and also set the command rate to 2 instead of 1, this also causes a lot of issues.

Comment: I didnt thought of that, will try and let know :)

Comment: also the 2300MHz for the NM frequency is also too high. Looks like you also try to OC the cpu, this may also cause issues.

Comment: OK, that really worked! For explanation, i have some OC switch for FSB i think on my MSI motherboard, i turned it on a few years back to 5 or 10%, it was running fine with my old RAM, so i forgot about the switch. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes memtest is relialable, if there is a problem with your ram, it will find it and display some red warnings.

Everythings seems to be ok in your capture

Answer (score 0):

Memtest86 is reliable for detecting memory problems that are caused by bad memory, but given your description I don't think that's what's going on here.
For example: if you have a very powerful cpu or gpu working very hard and a power supply that has trouble keeping up, your supply may not be able to supply your ram with full power and it may begin failing then.

Memtest86 does not replicate these conditions for its test, and honestly, I'm not sure where you could find a good memory testing utility that can run in parallel with a gpu benchmark.

I think my example is what is actually happening to you.
Perhaps try removing your graphics card or underclocking your cpu and running your intensive games then, with the graphics settings still the same.
Open task manager and make sure your game is still using the same amount of ram.
If the problem no longer occurs it is likely that the power draw was at fault.

Comment: I have 450W Evolve power suply (which is about ~300W for good trademark i guess). CPU got TPD 95W and GPU 65W, ill first try to change timing like @magicandre1981 sugested, then this. I can remove my GPU but cant really run much demanding game on my integrated graphics.